# Google charts with ChartRangeFilter are not showing multiple series

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, visualization, google-visualization

I'm using [google charts range filter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) with multiple series [column chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) at the upper.

So it looks like [image: this which is fine] It shows 3 series which is intended. **But** when I zoom in [image: blue bar not shown] blue bar not shown and also red bar shown only half. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally kind of solved this issue by manually setting ticks for bar chart shown on image. I set the ticks according to zoom level with another function.